# Adding manually a grid to a .tikz file generated by matlab2tikz

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-styles

I asked this question here [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29412888/converting-a-contourf-plot-with-grid-on-with-matlab2tikz-script/29427257?noredirect=1#comment47134717_29427257)

Now, I know of the existence of the problem with the conversion with the matlab2tikz script and the inclusion of a grid. [GridProb](https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz/issues/569)

How can I manually add a grid to this figure?

```
\begin{axis}[%
width=3.767433in,
height=3.541034in,
at={(0.753103in,0.477931in)},
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
xmin=0,
xmax=200,
xlabel={x-Achse},
xmajorgrids,
every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
ymin=10,
ymax=100,
ylabel={y-Achse},
ymajorgrids,
title={el. Potential V(x,y)},
colormap/jet,
colorbar,
colorbar style={separate axis lines,every outer x axis line/.append style={black},every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},every outer y axis line/.append style={black},every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}}},
point meta min=-4.95773818018795e-17,
point meta max=1.875
]
```

What I see in Matlab:
[Matlab_figure](http://pl.vc/41d05)

What I see in the compiled pdf:

[image]

Comment: Where is the figure? If you add `grid=both` (which is short for your `<x,y>majorgrids` to any axis it should be visible. Something might be overriding the options. Or add `zmajorgrids` if this is a top view of a 3D plot.

Comment: i add the link to the figure.

Comment: I think you might just need to add `axis on top` to the options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid is drawn behind the plots by default, so in your case it's not visible. Set `axis on top`, and you'll get a grid.